# how to find last record on page crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I look for solution  to find last record on page in crystal report ?

I have detail section a, b. I want to suppress detail section b only when printing last record on page.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the section expert, choose the section, and click on the suppress checkbox, and against it there is a symbol of cross, click on it and add the formula :

```
OnlastRecord //if this is true, then suppress will be true
```

**Edit :**

Now in case you have to get the last record per page, not the last record of whole data set, then you need to follow the following.

1. Add the display limit in the detail section to 10 records per page.
2. Use the next page after logic to shift the records greater than 10 count to next page.
3. Now in order to show particular section just below the 10th record, apply the logic to show and hide that section based on 10th record.

In case you need practical solution applying this logic, let me know I will post the whole concept of the same in a blog.

Comment: thanks for your reply but onlastRecord it will be true when it is the last record not per page

Comment: Yes make sure you add the number of records per page limit, like 10 per page, in case you need that help please let me know, I have done that as well.

Comment: this my solution but i look for a solution which can detect the last record per page thank you

Comment: have you set any limit per page to display records? Otherwise Crystal will put records as per page size, that cannot be tracked, as it will be dynamic, you must set limit of records per page, then find out the last record per page.

Comment: i can't expect the height of the record of the datable wich will be shown in crystal reports so this is not the optimal solution for me

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the answer as you are not getting my logic, the above answer will not work, you will have to make the record limit per page, by using logic, this I am trying to explain

Answer (score 1):

Try below approach.

Create a formula @initialize   //place in page header

```
Shared numbervar counter;
counter;
```

Create formula @count  //place where records are displayed

```
Shared numbervar counter;
Shared numbervar display;

counter:=counter+1;
display:=counter;
```

Create a formula @reset  //place in page footer below formula display

```
Shared numbervar counter;
counter:=0
```

Create a formula @display  //place in page footer above formula reset

```
Shared numbervar display;
display;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add sub details Section Below Your Data Set and insert the controls from page footer to new sub details section and suppress that page footer, and in suppress formula for new sub details section.

NOTE Make Sure you have Parameter For Rows Per Page Or Set Visible Rows Check To True and Set Constant Rows Per Page For Example Page Rows 25 :

```
if (recordnumber mod 25)=0 then
 false
else 
  if  OnLastRecord then
    false
  else
    true
```